# Use rails_xss on only certain pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xss

I'm running Rails 2.3.14 with the [rails_xss](https://github.com/rails/rails_xss) plugin. I have another plugin that I'm using to create my admin dashboard views. My problem is that rails_xss is escaping all the HTML that my dashboard plugin is generating. Is there a way to configure rails_xss to not escape pages matching `example.com/admin`, or based on directory (`app/views/admin`), or anything similar that would achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1):

It might be simpler to update your dashboard generating plugin to use **raw** or **html_safe** for content output.